# Show Sprite Image with intervals on Phaser

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, sprite, phaser-framework

I have a sprite where every single frame is an image that needs to be displayed individually.
Now, what i want to achieve is to show each image with interval, let's say a second or 2.

So far what i've tried:

```
var frames = [0, 13, 55, 22, 14];
var sprite;

$.each(frames, function (i, axis) {
    // x_axis, y_axis is dynamic
    sprite[i] = game.add.sprite(x_axis, y_axis, 'sprite', axis);
    sprite[i].animations.add('sprite' + i, [axis]);

    // I put 2 on second parameter hoping that it will prolong the interval
    // but it's not working. Sprites still shows fast like nothing change
    sprite[i].animations.play('sprite' + i, 2, false);
});
```

I also tried putting the sprite aniamations inside a `setTimeout` but what happened was, it will have a delay at start then eventually show all sprite image on canvas.

Any help. Just new to Phaser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The play time value is in frames per second delay between each frame. Try a much higher value.

Comment: i tried 2000 but still same? here my sprite is not moving..just displaying. thanks @PhotonStorm :D

Comment: What does `[axis]` contain within your each loop? Is it just a single number? Log it out and see. If it's just a single number then that would explain why it doesn't actually animate, as it needs to be a sequence of frames.

Comment: ya..its a number..not a sequence..if that so, is there a way to make an interval? it's like i want to show `0` --> 1 second --> `13`, and so on..

Comment: It needs to be a sequence of frames: `[0, 13, 24, ...]` - then the delay given to the `play` call will be the delay between each of those frames. An animation with just 1 frame isn't an animation at all, it's just a static image.